# Issue tokens via API

Tags: tokens, api

I can issue my own tokens via cleos, it works fine. But I can't find any reference on how to issue tokens via EOS API. Is there any way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you issue tokens via Cleos it creates, signs and sends a transaction containing the necessary data to call the [issue-action](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp#L27) of the token smart contract.

If you want to do the same via API (assuming via RPC-API), you need to create, sign and push a transaction containing similar data. Libraries to do so are for example [EOS-JS](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) and [EOS-SHARP](https://github.com/liquiidio/eos-sharp) they also contain documentation and examples.